# UXSDK Sample code (iOS) does not show video feed from P4P V1 when photo aspect ratio is 3:2

Tags: dji-sdk

**Problem:**

After upgrading DJI iOS UXSDK from 4.4 to 4.6, my sample code does not show video preview from Phantom 4 Pro V1 when it photo aspect ratio is 3:2. The whole screen (except its widgets) is black.

The same code works perfectly on my Mavic Pro, Phantom 4, Phantom 4 Pro V2, Inspire 1, and has no problem running on the same Phantom 4 Pro V1 when its aspected ratio is set to 16:9 or 4:3.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Get a **Phantom 4 Pro V1** (01.05.0600 + RC 01.04.01.00), and set its aspect ratio to **3:2**.
2. Clone [Mobile-UXSDK-iOS](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS) (**any version from 4.5 to 4.6.1**, including the latest commit **#0b7d1ec**).
3. Install dependencies and paste SDK API key in Info.plist.
4. Run on iPhone/iPad (iOS 11.4) and connect to aircraft.
5. After both Registered and Connected turn to YES, enter the **Default Layout** at first row.

**Other findings**

I don't think that is due to some hardware issues, because I have found:

- DJI Go 4, and SDK 4.4 work perfectly on same devices, same settings.
- The same project running in iOS Simulator can show video feed transmitted via [SDK Bridge](https://itunes.apple.com/app/sdk-bridge/id1263583917). I guess it is because it uses software decoding.
- Someone mentioned similar issue a month ago when he was trying Mobile SDK without UXSDK, [No Video Feed with different camera Image sizes](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/264), but get no response.

I believe there is something I forgot to do, or SDK developers forget to mention in the sample code, tutorials and release notes.

Anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this scenario on my iPhone 7 Plus Version 11.4.1 on the Swift iOS UXSDK 4.6.1.

Video previewer worked in aspect ratio 3:2 if switched from another ratio however you're right, the screen is black if launched in ratio 3:2.

This appears to be a bug - please send an email to open a ticket at dev@dji.com and let us know if you built this with Swift or Obj-C

Comment: I'm using Swift sample code. Switching to 16:9 wakes the video previewer up, but after switching back it gets stuck again.